# How can I know if the verb the same as the subject

Tags: gramática, complemento-directo

I have the following two questions :

> ¿Nos vendáis vuestro coche? --> Sí/(No, no) Os lo vendamos.
>
> ¿Visitáis hoy a Antonio? --> Sí/(No, no) nos lo visitamos.

My question is how can I recognize which question I will have to use the verb as the subject for example in second question the subject is *nos* and we have visit**amos** which appiles to *nos*. Unlike the first question we have os and we don't have vend**ais** we have vend**amos** which apply to nos that doesn't appear in the answer unlike the second question.

Any methods/tip how to find the right verb?

Comment: Note that the example sentences are incorrect. They should be _sí, os lo vendemos_ (do not mistake _vender_ with _vendar_, they are different verbs) and _sí, lo visitamos_ (you have to drop the _nos_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you are mixing things up. The subject in both questions is *vosotros*, and in both answers is *nosotros*; only in Spanish we tend to omit the subject when it is known or easy to infer. And that *nos* in the second answer is completely superfluous.

In the first question, *nos* is not the subject, but the *indirect object*. It indicates to whom you are performing the action; in this case, I ask whether you (subject) are selling the car (direct object) to us (indirect object).

I will also assume that you made a mistake and used the verb *vendar* (to put bandages) instead of *vender* (to sell). Then your examples would be:

> ¿Nos vendéis vuestro coche? --> Sí/(No, no) os lo vendemos.
>
> ¿Visitáis hoy a Antonio? --> Sí/(No, no) lo visitamos.

Answer (score 0):

Are you plural selling us your car? no we are not selling it to you.

Did you visit Antonio today? no we did not visit him.

Does that help you here? Do not forget that pronouns are often omitted in Spanish when they are clear from the context.